# database remains empty

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net, database-restore

STEP 1: I backup the database using this code snippet (It works fine)

```
Public Shared Sub BackupDatabase()
        Dim sConnect As String = My.Settings.LICConnectionString
        Dim dbName As String

        Using cnn As New SqlConnection(sConnect)
            cnn.Open()
            dbName = cnn.Database.ToString()

            Dim sc As New ServerConnection(cnn)
            Dim sv As New Server(sc)

            ' Check that I'm connected to the user instance
            Console.WriteLine(sv.InstanceName.ToString())

            ' Create backup device item for the backup
            Dim bdi As New BackupDeviceItem("C:\Backup\LIC.bak", DeviceType.File)

            ' Create the backup informaton
            Dim bk As New Backup()
            bk.Devices.Add(bdi)
            bk.Action = BackupActionType.Database
            bk.BackupSetDescription = "SQL Express is a great product!"
            bk.BackupSetName = "SampleBackupSet"
            bk.Database = dbName
            bk.ExpirationDate = New Date(2007, 5, 1)
            bk.LogTruncation = BackupTruncateLogType.Truncate

            ' Run the backup
            bk.SqlBackup(sv)
            MsgBox("Your backup is complete.")
        End Using
    End Sub
```

STEP 2: I delete all the data from the tables(so the database is empty).

STEP 3: Restore the database from the backup file  using this code snippet (it does not throw any error and executes fine)

```
 Private Sub Restore(ByVal ConnectionString As String, ByVal DatabaseFullPath As String, ByVal backUpPath As String)
        Using con As New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
            con.Open()

            Dim UseMaster As String = "USE master"
            Dim UseMasterCommand As New SqlCommand(UseMaster, con)
            UseMasterCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

            Dim Alter1 As String = "ALTER DATABASE [" & DatabaseFullPath & "] SET Single_User WITH Rollback Immediate"
            Dim Alter1Cmd As New SqlCommand(Alter1, con)
            Alter1Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            Dim Restore As String = "RESTORE DATABASE [" & DatabaseFullPath & "] FROM DISK = N'" & backUpPath & "' WITH  FILE = 1,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10"
            Dim RestoreCmd As New SqlCommand(Restore, con)
            RestoreCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            Dim Alter2 As String = "ALTER DATABASE [" & DatabaseFullPath & "] SET Multi_User"
            Dim Alter2Cmd As New SqlCommand(Alter2, con)
            Alter2Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            MsgBox("Successful")
        End Using
    End Sub
```

But it does not show the data in the tables...i mean after i restore the database i should get the old data from the backup file ...but the database tables remains empty..

Can u guide me on this??

Comment: Your assumptions are incorrect; You say both back up and restore "works fine", yet that's obviously *not true*.

Comment: it does not throw any error...any idea where am i going wrong?

Comment: No idea *at all*, because you have never even tested if the backup *really worked*...

Comment: @AndrewBarber the backup works...because i get the .bak file in the backup folder.

Comment: You have no idea what is in that backup file. It could be empty. It could be the wrong db. It might be corrupt. It might be the wrong bak file altogether...

Comment: @AndrewBarber how do i check it ?? please help me..i really need this to work.

Comment: You need to verify that the back up and restore work at all, through existing tools (SSMS, for example) before you go expanding your potential source of errors to your own code, too.

Comment: What value does your `DatabaseFullPath` variable contain?? In your SQL statements, this should be just the logical database name (e.g. `MyDatabase`) - but the naming would indicate that you might have the entire path and file name for the database in that variable - that would be the wrong thing to put your `ALTER DATABASE ....` statements.....

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is that you are trying to use the database path in your SQL statements rather than the database name.

Assuming that your connection string is opening the database that you wish to restore to initially, the restore method can be rewritten as follows:

```
Private Sub Restore(ByVal ConnectionString As String, ByVal DatabaseFullPath As String, ByVal backUpPath As String)
    Using con As New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
        con.Open()

        Dim sDatabaseName As String

        sDatabaseName = con.Database

        Dim UseMaster As String = "USE master"
        Dim UseMasterCommand As New SqlCommand(UseMaster, con)
        UseMasterCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Dim Alter1 As String = "ALTER DATABASE [" & sDatabaseName & "] SET Single_User WITH Rollback Immediate"
        Dim Alter1Cmd As New SqlCommand(Alter1, con)
        Alter1Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Dim Restore As String = "RESTORE DATABASE [" & sDatabaseName & "] FROM DISK = N'" & backUpPath & "' WITH  FILE = 1,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10"
        Dim RestoreCmd As New SqlCommand(Restore, con)
        RestoreCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Dim Alter2 As String = "ALTER DATABASE [" & sDatabaseName & "] SET Multi_User"
        Dim Alter2Cmd As New SqlCommand(Alter2, con)
        Alter2Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        MsgBox("Successful")
    End Using
End Sub
```